# Nginx server names priority

Tags: nginx, server-name

I have two server sections for nginx in different files.

The first one:

```
server {
  server_name _;
  ...   
}
```

The second one:

```
server {
  server_name ~someRegex;
  ...
}
```

I have some constraints - I can't change the first server section (i.e. I can't edit first file)

Documentation says the following about server names priority:

> 1. exact name
> 2. longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
> 3. longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
> 4. first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

As I understand `server_name _` is used as catch-all server.

So when I have request from host matched someRegex request is handled by first server section. Is there a way to handle these request by second server section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.

`_` simply renders the `server_name` invalid. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names).

What makes a `server` block the default is either being defined first for a given port or being defined with the `listen ... default_server` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

So your configuration will work as you expect, assuming that your regex is valid and that the second server block has indeed been installed by `nginx`. Check your error log after reloading `nginx` and/or test the configuration using

```
nginx -t
```